# Handle ISO time format in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I am processing a log file which has timestamp in either of the following format:

```
2019-03-29 12:11:26.411770+0100
```

or

```
2019-03-29 17:09:42.321698-0700
```

In my code, I can handle the timestamp with floats as following:

```
df["New Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

However, this doesn't work with the timestamp I have with + and - extensions (as shown above). Is there anything in datetime package which handles these GMT extensions?

Comment: Use only `df["New Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)`

Comment: but later on, I need to do some arithmetic operations on timestamps (subtract two timestamps). Not sure how do that with these extensions

Comment: You can use `df["New Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, utc=True)` to convert everything to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question specifically about the `datetime` package:

```
>>>  datetime.datetime.strptime("2019-03-29 17:09:42.321698-0700","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z")
datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 29, 17, 9, 42, 321698, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=61200)))
```